# Obter variáveis PHP via JavaScript sem recarregar página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando passar os resultados do *foreach* para `<span id="mostra_ref">` ao click do mouse, porém dessa forma está passando apenas o último valor da função *explode*, mesmo o script estando dentro do *foreach*. Preciso mostrar cada referência clicada.

```
<div class="entry-summary">
    <span id="mostra_ref"><?php echo @$referencia_1  ?></span>
    //primeiro mostra um valor do banco de dados
    //ao clicar em qualquer referência na classe sku imprime apenas F015 
</div>
<div class="product-variations">
    <ul class="variations list-unstyled">
        <?php
        $aux = explode(",", $referencia);  
        foreach($aux as $outras_refs) : ?>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a class="zoom">

                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $('a').on('click',function(){

                        $('#mostra_ref').html('<?php echo $outras_refs; ?>');

                        });
                    </script>


                    <div class="sku"><?php echo$outras_refs; ?></div>
                    //IMPRIME F014,F013,F015   

                </a>
           </div>
        </li>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: O problema é o seguinte: o PHP está montando a página toda. Depois que o PHP faz o trabalho dele é que a página é enviada para o navegador. Nessa hora, tudo que era PHP já foi substituido pelos valores que você programou. Olhe o código fonte pelo browser, que vai ser mais fácil você entender o que está sendo enviado. Você está enviando 3 vezes o JS, cada um com um valor, então o que vai valer é o último. Uma solução seria você por um ID diferente em cada "a", e usar $(<?php echo $id; ?>) em cada uma.

Comment: Eu estava olhando isso agora, cada valor está certo quando inspeciono cada elemento. Vou ver como posso resolver.

Comment: Você poderia, por exemplo, usar uma função só, e montar uma variável de JS em cada uma. Ou mesmo, usar uma propriedade `data-ref="<?php echo $ref; ?>"` em cada âncora, e pegar o valor no onclick.

Comment: Quando você diz criar uma id para cada "a" é criar um incremento tipo <a id="<?php echo $id++ ?>"  e chamar no Js  $('<?php echo $id++ >').on('click',function(){ .....  ? não deu certo.
Eu tirei o script do foreach mais ainda continua pegando o último resultado.
Vou tentar abordar com $("a").attr(‘data-referencia');

Comment: Não precisa complicar, basta usar o próprio $outras_refs pra criar o ID. E o script fica fora do foreach, basta uma vez só. Dentro do function é que você vai pegar o ID correto e usar no echo. Mas em JS esta parte final, não em PHP.

Comment: Não obtive êxito ! Pode exemplificar por favor apenas como configurar o id no JavaScript?

Comment: Só de ver seu código, percebo que você está fazendo isso errado. Há formas melhores de fazer isso, eu não pretendo julgar, mas esse código precisa ser melhorado e muito, só de ver você colocar uma função em JavaScript dentro do loop já não é uma coisa boa de se ver. Além disso, colocar o @ para disfarçar o erro... bom, eu faria isso tudo diferente... por isso não vou nem me dar o trabalho de responder sua pergunta.

Comment: Se não for responder, não precisa comentar. Tudo o que você disse sobre erros eu sei, mais não é o problema em questão. Isso é um site de perguntas e respostas, não de análises. @IvanFerrer

Comment: Meus comentários são orientações para o seu crescimento como profissional da área, você deveria aprender com seus erros, já que você já os reconhece, deveria procurar evitá-los, e não "tapar o sol com a peneira". A sua pergunta e seu código precisa ser melhorado, então uma resposta aqui não resolveria a questão como um todo, pois seria contribuir com a extensão do seu problema. O site também tem uma área de comentário, e quem trabalha na área de TI é um analista, então não faz sentido sua colocação.

Comment: Infelizmente a política de tratamento de erros da empresa é @, por não usar framework, e ter mais "tempo", meus códigos eu trato. Mais tudo bem, entendo o que diz, agradeço as orientações. @Ivan Ferrer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que a variável PHP $referencia = "F014,F013,F015", esse deve ser o código que vocÊ busca (não é possível executar aqui, pois tem PHP...):

```js
    $('a').on('click',function(){

        $('#mostra_ref').html($(this).find('.sku').html());

    });
```

```html
<div class="entry-summary">
    <span id="mostra_ref">F15</span>
</div>
<div class="product-variations">
    <ul class="variations list-unstyled">
        <?php
        $aux = explode(",", $referencia);  
        foreach($aux as $outras_refs) : ?>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a class="zoom">
                    <div class="sku"><?php echo $outras_refs; ?></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi criando uma *id* para cada "a" com a própria variável *$outras_refs* como proposto no comentário. Mais ainda gostaria de **outra resposta** que não se aplica a tag script dentro do loop, o que é uma má prática.

```
<div class="entry-summary">
    <span id="mostra_ref"><?php echo @$referencia_1  ?></span>
    //primeiro mostra um valor do banco de dados
    //ao clicar em qualquer referência na classe sku imprime a referência correspondente 
</div>
<div class="product-variations">
    <ul class="variations list-unstyled">
        <?php
        $aux = explode(",", $referencia);  
        foreach($aux as $outras_refs) : ?>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a class="zoom" id="<?php echo$outras_refs; ?>">

                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $('a').on('click',function(){


                        $( "#<?php echo$outras_refs; ?>" ).click(function() {
                            $( "#mostra_ref" ).html('<?php echo$outras_refs; ?>');
                        });
                    </script>


                    <div class="sku"><?php echo$outras_refs; ?></div>
                    //IMPRIME F014,F013,F015   

                </a>
           </div>
        </li>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja minha resposta, acho que é isso que procura e ainda remove a repetição, desnecessária, de script.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, há uma solução, talvez pode ser considerada "gambiarrenta", mas que irá resolver, **sem usar qualquer id e sem alteração no PHP**! Mas, melhor que isso irei dizer "como detectei" tal solução.

**Observe este trecho:**

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $('a').on('click',function(){

                    $('#mostra_ref').html('<?php echo $outras_refs; ?>');

                    });
                </script>


                <div class="sku"><?php echo$outras_refs; ?></div>
```

Observe que o conteúdo do `.html()` o mesmo que existe dentro do `div class="sku"`, que inclusive está dentro do próprio `a` que é clicado, perfeito!

**Portanto faça o seguinte:**

Defina o `.on('click'` para:

```
  $('a').on('click',function(){
  var html = $(this).find('.sku').html();

  $('#mostra_ref').html(html);
  });
```

Isso irá, exatamente:

```
Ao clicar no `a`.
Seta o `html` para encontrar o item de classe `sku` e pegar seu html.
Injeta o HTML do html no item de id `mostra_ref`.
```

**O código completo:**

```
<div class="entry-summary">
    <span id="mostra_ref"><?php echo @$referencia_1  ?></span>
    //primeiro mostra um valor do banco de dados
    //ao clicar em qualquer referência na classe sku imprime apenas F015 
</div>
<div class="product-variations">
    <ul class="variations list-unstyled">
        <?php
        $aux = explode(",", $referencia);  
        foreach($aux as $outras_refs) : ?>
        <li>
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <a class="zoom">
                    <div class="sku"><?php echo$outras_refs; ?></div>
                    //IMPRIME F014,F013,F015   
                </a>
           </div>
        </li>
        <?php
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a').on('click',function(){
  var html = $(this).find('.sku').html();

  $('#mostra_ref').html(html);
  });
</script>
```

Essa solução é mais leve, irá economizar banda e carregar mais rapidamente. =)
Lembre: se está declarando duas coisas iguais é porque há algo errado.

**Teste isso:**

> Lembre-se isso NÃO REPRESENTA O SEU CÓDIGO INTREGRALMENTE. O
>   Stackoverflow não processa PHP, portanto isso é apenas uma
>   demonstração com o MESMO JAVASCRIPT, com dados de exemplos!

```js
  $('a').on('click',function(){
  var html = $(this).find('.sku').html();

  $('#mostra_ref').html(html);
  });
```

```css
#mostra_ref {
  background-color:#FFFF00;
  }

p {
  
  font-size:10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Seus links:</p>
<a class="zoom">
  <div class="sku">F013</div>
</a>
<a class="zoom">
  <div class="sku">F014</div>
</a>
<a class="zoom">
  <div class="sku">F015</div>
</a>
<br>
<p>Seu mostra_ref:</p>
<span id="mostra_ref"></span>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Inkeliz, sua solução também funciona porém vou pontuar o Jhonnyjks por ter menos pontos, além de ter eliminado uma linha do código.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, é fácil. Eu entendi você quer usar os dados tanto no php quando no javascript.

Primeiro evita esse loop na tag script. isso não fica legal. depois tu faz um foreach para gerar um json. dependendo da quantidades de dados você fazer isso na página html mesmo, dentro de uma div com display:none. Aí você pode usar esses dados json no php e depois que estiver impresso na página html você pode usá-lo no javascript. se a quantidade de dados for muito grande faça um arquivo json mesmo.

espero te-lo ajudado.

Comment: Sou novato em JS portanto não entendi bem, apesar de bem explicado. Meu código funcionou mais estou ciente da má prática da tag script no loop. Eu tirei que tinha aceitado minha resposta. Se quiser exemplificar com o código, talvez eu possa dar os 50 pontos para você mais não estou certo se vai funcionar @Thiago Lima, creio que sim pois o botão está ativo.